# slope of lines in interaction plot in ggplot2 does not match estimates

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, interaction

I am trying to plot the interaction effects from a multiple linear regression using ggplot2. However, the slope of the lines plotted do not match what they should be based on the estimates returned by the lm function.

Here is my code:

`lm.sense <- lm(sense_of_belonging ~ active*mathEAL + MathID + comfort_speaking, data=Data)`

````
library(ggplot2)
p.sense <- ggplot(lm.sense, aes(y=sense_of_belonging, x=active, color=mathEAL)) + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)```

Does ggplot not hold the other variables constant?
````

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 works with data.frames and doesn't naturally know what to do with an `lm` object.  (Try `plot(lm.sense)` to see what base R offers here.)

Your ggplot call is using the underlying data from `Data` (tucked away inside your `lm.sense` object) to make a plot where x = `active` and y = `sense_of_belonging`. It uses that underlying data to do a linear regression that doesn't relate to the `mathEAL`, `MathID`, and `comfort_speaking` variables. Compare these:  (they have the same result)

```
lm.mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)
ggplot(lm.mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Depending on what you want to do, you could show some of the impact of other variables within your `geom_smooth` by referencing those:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = as.character(cyl))) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, fullrange = TRUE)
```

[image]

It would help to understand what kind of output you're hoping to generate to give more specific suggestions.

Comment: That is helpful thank you for the comment! I want to plot the lines that stem from the regression coefficient for the variables involved in the interaction, i.e., holding all the other variables constant. Do you have any example code of how to do this? Would it be easier to just find the equations myself and plot them?